# Getting byte code of classes.dex in android app

Tags: java, android, dalvik, disassembly

I'm trying to disassemble classes.dex (or at least get something like byte code in JVM) file from Android application programmatic. I found [this specification](http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html) but i couldn't understand does Dalvik VM has byte code, or just assembler? Does it have different command length like x86 or same like JVM? Is there anything like [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) exists for DVM?

Comment: Just in case you're not familiar with it, baksmali can disassemble dex files into a human readable text format, with smali doing the reverse.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/instruction-formats.html contains the detailed info you need to parse each instruction format.

Answer (score 0):

That page lists all of the bytecodes. What you need is the .dex file format: http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html

You need to parse the dex file before you can start disassembling the bytecode, which is located in the code_item structure associated with a method.

Comment: And neither the JVM nor DalvikVM use fixed width commands. The first byte is the operand and 0 or more parameter bytes may follow.

Comment: Your second sentence makes no sense at all. decompilation and disassembly are two separate processes. The goal of decompilation is to convert bytecode/assembly back to the original high level language it was compiled from. The goal of disassembly is to produce a human-readable direct text representation of the bytecode.

Comment: @JesusFreke - Maybe not the best terminology to use, but it is correct. I meant decompile as in to pull apart the compilation that is the dex file. The dex contains all of the compiled (compiler sense) byte code in one file (English meaning of compilation).

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand what you mean now. I think "parse" might be a better word :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing i searched for: [Dalvik opcodes](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html). From this table you can understand what is the length of the commands and how to get bytecode out of *.dex.